# Jquery UI autocomplete works fine but getting blank result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have used Jquery autocomplete example from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp. I have included all the specific code from the reference site but that doesn't work in my local. 
I want only company name to be search in it.

[Here i am attaching image to get the exact idea what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSuFj.jpg)

```js
<script>
  $( function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#company_name" ).autocomplete({
   source: "http://localhost:5050/api/v1/web-customer-list",
      type: "GET",
      minLength: 1,
      autoSelect: true,
      autoFocus: true,
      dataType : "json",
       response: function( event, ui ) {
       var responseObj = ui.content[0];
          var companyNameList = [] ;
           for(var i = 0 ; i<= 6 ; i ++){
              companyNameList.push(responseObj[i].company.company_name) ;
           }
        },

      select: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(ui);
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.company.company_name + " aka " + ui.item.id );
   }
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data that is returned in the AJAX call. Also you need to return the Array. `return companyNameList;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked over the example and made some adjustments to fit what you appear to be doing.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0Lajrcfv/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="companyName">Company Name: </label>
  <input id="companyName">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  function log(message) {
    $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
    $("#log").scrollTop(0);
  }

  $("#companyName").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var companyNameList = [];
      $.ajax({
        //url: "http://localhost:5050/api/v1/web-customer-list",
        //type: "GET",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          json: JSON.stringify({
            company: {
              company_name: [
                "Apple",
                "Google",
                "IBM",
                "HP",
                "Yahoo!",
                "AltaVista",
                "Yelp",
                "2600"
              ]
            }
          })
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respObj) {
          for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            companyNameList.push({
              id: i,
              value: respObj.company.company_name[i]
            });
          }
          resp(companyNameList);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    autoSelect: true,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      log("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id);
    }
  });
});
```

So, as you can see from the example, the `source` option can accept the response from a string or callback function. The callback function is passed two parameters, `request` and `response`.

> The callback gets two arguments:
>
> A `request` object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
>
> A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Based on your code, it looks like you are not going to filter clientside, you're just going to accept the top 6 from whatever your `GET` request returns. So we just ignore `req.term` in my example. We're then only really concerned about collecting the results, formatting them properly, and returning them to `resp()`.

For my working example, we `POST` the data so it can be echo'd back as a response. Based on your example, you're expecting an object of some type, roughly similar to:

```
[{
  company: {
    company_name
  }
}]
```

If you want your version to work, where you call the URL via `GET`, the data returned should be:

> An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

For example:

```
[{
  label: "Apple",
  value: 1
},
{
  label: "Google",
  value: 2
}];
```

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much that works for me.. Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I have just one question. you have keep static data in it at the moment but how could i get dynamic data. Can you please show me the format for it.

Comment: That would be provided by your API. Just call your get.